# What happens to the gain of a switched capacitor circuit when a resistor is placed in series with the input voltage driving source?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, gain

Why might that happen?

This was an interview question I received

Comment: perhaps because ideal voltage sources don't exist.

Comment: Depends on RC and the switching frequency. (If R is small enough it won't make much difference.)  What was your answer?

Comment: I stated about variation in value of R. Similar to yours.@GeorgeHerold

Answer (score 1):

Your question touches a typical problem of all S/C circuits because the real on-resistance of the switches must be considered during the design of S/C blocks. Of course, such an on-resistance is nothing else than a series resistance together with an ideal switch.

**Hence, the answer to this question is as follows**: As long as the resulting time constant RC is sufficiently small if compared with the time available for charging the capacitor (50% takt period) the function of the S/C block will be (nearly) not altered. If the resistor is too large the capacitor will not get fully charged and transfer errors will occur. Typically, this problem always sets the upper limit for the takt rate.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the series resistance in your question, a switched capacitor circuit acts as a variable resistor between input and output (where the equivalent resistance is related to switching frequency and capacitance). Think of it this way....

[image]

The final formula equates current flowing into the left hand node with the voltage differential across both nodes (Vin - Vout) multiplied by fs*C.

This is basically ohms law, I = VR where R is fs*C

In other words, a switched capacitor network is a "series resistor" but remember it's subject to sampling theory and can only be reasonably regarded as a series resistor when Fs is significantly higher than the signal inputted.

Back to your questio. Adding a resistor in series with Vin or Vout is basically that - you are now adding a resistor i.e. total resistance becomes R1 + R2 where R2 is the series resistance of the switched capacitor network.

[Here's](https://classes.yale.edu/04-05/enas627b/lectures/EENG427l04aswcap.pdf) a nice article on it.

Comment: Andy-I must admit that I am not too happy with the "nice" article. Example: In the picture you have shown (copied from the referenced article) we have, obviously, Vin=Vout. Therefore, where is the current resp. the resistance to be simulated by the S/C block? How can a current go from Vin to Vout (as mentioned in the text)

Comment: What makes it so obvious that Vin=Vout?

Comment: Perhaps I should add that on page 6 of the mentioned article a more descriptive expanation of the S/C principle is given. In this context, it is important to realize that the voltage Vout is not really an "output voltage" but also a voltage SOURCE that in practice is realized with another (large) capacitor.

Comment: @Brian,agreed not "obvious", but has a beginner another chance than to think that the capacitor is charged to Vin and makes it available (as Vout) during the second takt period ? That was my point - perhaps not good expressed. (Text:... "transferred from Vin to Vout").

Answer (score 0):

Are we talking a circuit like this? What gain are they referring to?

[image]

The circuit would simply look like a resistor Req = 1/(C*f). I would think that the gain would decrease because adding a resistor (R1) to the input simply makes a voltage divider, like so:

[image]

Comment: Yes, a circuit similar yours.

Comment: No - I don`t think that this simple voltage divider model is a good equivalent to the described problem. For example, Where is the common node "Vout"? Between both parts (R1 resp. S/C block)? No, of course not.